# Similar functionality to windows Jumplists for Mac OSx?

Tags: macos, lazarus

I'm converting an application (originally written in Delphi XE3 - converted to Pascal / Lazarus) from Windows to Mac.  The program uses windows Jumplists to pass parameters to the application allowing it to be controlled from the taskbar without leaving other applications.  i.e. - right click on the icon in the taskbar and select the function you want from the list in the jumplist (which is dynamically populated by my application).  The jumplist then passes a parameter back to the my application which handles the message and takes an action.  (I have a video of this in practice if I've not been clear [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=stiTd7kHwPY#t=113))

I'm not a Mac user and I'm struggling to find anything equivalent in the OSx world.  Is there anything similar I can use in the Mac world or is this destined to be a windows only feature?  Any ideas welcome - I'm not precious about how it works exactly - but I'd love to have something I can use.

Comment: Do you mean the custom Dock menus? Like when you click on Finder in the Dock, it has "New Finder Window", "New Smart Folder" etc

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Mac OS X provides a similar function, the Dock Tile Menus. Unfortunately, however, there is no direct support for the ApplicationManager in Lazarus and Free Pascal.

You might use the information provided at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/tasks/docktasks.html to convert XCode's C header files to Pascal and implement your own solution.